# Google sheets Alert message

Tags: google-apps-script, alert

I know I am missing something.  I want to do an alert message before user deletes data in google sheets

I believe I need an "else".  I have tried to combine two function in one but get an error.  Here are the two actions  I want an alert message and based on user picking "OK" it will clear the range.  Or user presses "Cancel" and alert window disappears.

```
function alertMessage() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You are about to clear all of this week's data.  Please make sure you have Pressed the SAVE button on each ROSTER page FIRST", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(result);}

function clearRange() {
  
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('365Data');
  sheet.getRange('A2:E').clearContent();

}
```

I but both actions under one set of brackets:

```
function alertMessage() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You are about to clear all of this week's data.  Please make sure you have Pressed the SAVE button on each ROSTER page FIRST", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(result)

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('365Data');
  sheet.getRange('A2:E').clearContent();

}
```

but got an error message script function could not be found

Comment: Take a look at this article [Ui Dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html)

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the link.  I got it working with this:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Display a dialog box with a title, message, and "Yes" and "No" buttons. The user can also
// close the dialog by clicking the close button in its title bar.
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.alert('You are about to RESET ALL THE DATA for the week.', 'Are you sure you want to continue?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
Thank you I got it working with the link you sent

    Process the user's response.
if (response == ui.Button.NO) {
Logger.log('The user clicked "No."');
`} else { const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data');
  sheet.getRange('A2:E').clearContent();
}
  Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
}
```